# Github ssh-action configuration to deploy changes in django application

Tags: python, django, github-actions

I have set up a workflow to execute a script which essentially just makemigrations, migrates and runs collectstic before restartting gunicorn and reloading nginx.

I have configured my settings.py file to pick up the secret and some other variables from the environment. The problem is though, that the script executes successfully when I manually ssh into the server and run it whereas when doing the same via ssh-action, it throws an error

My script

```sh
# Cd into the required directory
cd myproject/

# Pull the changes
git pull

# Makemigrations and migrate
myenv/bin/python manage.py makemigrations
myenv/bin/python manage.py migrate

# Collectstatic
myenv/bin/python manage.py collectstatic --noinput

# Restart gunicorn and reload nginx
systemctl restart gunicorn
systemctl reload nginx
```

My action config

```yml
name: deploying changes
on:
  push:
    branches: [main]

jobs:
  build:
    name: Build
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: deploying changes
        uses: appleboy/ssh-action@master
        with:
          host: ${{ secrets.HOST }}
          username: ${{ secrets.USERNAME }}
          key: ${{ secrets.KEY }}
          script: |
            sh deploy_changes.sh
```

This successfully connects to the server but following is the error thrown when it tries to execute the makemigrations and migrate command

```
err:     raise ImproperlyConfigured("The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty.")
err: django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty.
```

Also, I have a .env file on server and I use the `python-dotenv` package to load the environment variables in the `settings.py` file

```py
from dotenv import load_dotenv
load_dotenv(verbose=True)
```

Please help with the configuration. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it by using the following:

```yaml
name: deploying changes
on:
  push:
    branches: [main]

jobs:
  build:
    name: Build
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: deploying changes
        uses: appleboy/ssh-action@master
        env:
          DJANGO_SECRET_KEY: ${{ secrets.DJANGO_SECRET_KEY }}
        with:
          host: ${{ secrets.HOST }}
          username: ${{ secrets.USERNAME }}
          key: ${{ secrets.KEY }}
          envs: DJANGO_SECRET_KEY
          script: |
            export DJANGO_SECRET_KEY=$DJANGO_SECRET_KEY
            sh deploy_changes.sh
            ls -al
```

The important points here are:

- You can manually export all the required environment variables by first supplying them in the env part of your configuration.
- Github has renamed the `master` branch to `main`, be sure to account for that.

Comment: I wrote a similar bash script, but when I executed it, it asked me github credentials for ```git pull```. How will we handle this, if say, I want the deployment to be automated at the ```push```?

Comment: You can add your ssh keys to your server and then it would be auto authenticated or you could use a token and pull by supplying your id and password in the url for git pull